# C++ Calculator Exits

Tags: c++, calculator

I have a problem with my first program in C++.I wrote this calculator but for some reason when I type the operation character it quits.It doesn't show any error or something,it just exits.
This is the code from Visual C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float n3;
    int op;
    cout << "Welcome to my calculator" << endl;
    cout << "Type the first number: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Type the second number: ";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Type the number for the operation" << endl;
    cout << "1 = addition" << endl;
    cout << "2 = subvision" << endl;
    cout << "3 = multiply" << endl;
    cout << "4 = division" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    if(op == 1)
    {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        cout << "The result is " << n3 << endl;
    }
    if(op == 2)
    {
        n3 = n1 - n2;
        cout << "The result is " << n3 << endl;
    }
    if(op == 3)
    {
        n3 = n1 * n2;
        cout << "The result is " << n3 << endl;
    }
    if(op == 4)
    {
        n3 = n1 / n2;
        cout << "The result is " << n3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works just fine. Run it in the console (cmd.exe).

Comment: Or maybe it prints the result, THEN exits, but those happen so close together that you don't get to see the result? Try adding an extra `cin >> something;` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Works for me - looks like your output is being piped to the VisualC's output log. Run it in the console to see what it is really doing.

Comment: If you are running from an IDE, set a breakpoint on the `return 0;` line, and try running again in debug mode.

Comment: just add a cin >> op at the end to wait for input. It works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `switch` statement instead of your multiple `if`s.  Then your default statement can catch what is happening when none of your expected cases match.

```
switch (op)
{
case 1:
{
   // add
   break;
}
// other cases
default
{
   // something unexpected, print an error
}
}
```

Comment: This does not anser the question. This would be a better comment.

Answer (score -1):

You could fix that whit inserting

```
system("pause");
```

at the end just before the return (if you're coding under windows)

Comment: `system("pause")` is considered bad practice for many reasons. Better use `cin.get()`